# How to default the value of a conditionally rendered checkbox in a screen in a flow to false?

Tags: visual-workflow, visual-flows, screen-flow

I have a flow where there are four checkboxes in a screen but one of them is conditionally rendered. That checkbox has its "Default Value" set to `{!$GlobalConstant.False}`, but that assignment appears not to be made unless the checkbox is rendered.

So later on in the flow when that checkbox is assigned to a checkbox record field an error results because null is being set rather than false:

[image: assignment screen shot]

with debug output of:

> acl__AccreditedInvestorIndividualItemD__c
> {!AccreditedInvestorIndividualItemD} (null)
>
> Accredited Investor Individual Type D: value not of required type: .

What pattern can be used to avoid this problem?

Comment: I think you can create a formula that would take the value of the checkbox and default to false if no value is found and then use that in your assignment

Comment: Hi @Novarg, You mean a formula SObject field? I'd like to fix this in the flow if possible.

Comment: Hi @Novarg, I see the Formula resource type now in the flow editor. Yes I'm a newbie to flows. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Novarg post this as an answer and I'll accept it so we can close this Q/A off.

Comment: `If a screen input component is hidden because it doesn’t meet conditional visibility requirements, its value is set to null. ...` [SFDC Help](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_considerations_design_conditional_visibility.htm&type=5)

Comment: @KeithC glad it helped, answer posted :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your screen flow you can go to the toolbox(on the left) and click 'New Resource':

[image]

Then create a new resource of type formula that would evaluate to `true` only if the checkbox is checked:

[image]

Then you can use this formula in your assignment and it should be either true(only if checkbox was checked) or false(all other scenarios)